# Bulk insert/update in couchbase lite mobile iOS

Tags: ios, couchbase-lite

I am using couchbase lite mobile iOS framework for cache. Is there a way to have bulk insert or bulk update in couchbase lite in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

In v1.x, You can use [inTransaction](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.4/references/couchbase-lite/couchbase-lite/database/database/index.html#boolean-runintransactionrunintransactiondelegate-delegate) on CBLDatabase. As per the specs -

```
Runs the block within a transaction. If the block returns NO, the transaction is rolled back.
    Use this when performing bulk write operations like multiple inserts/updates; it saves the 
    overhead of multiple SQLite commits, greatly improving performance.
```